# Coq: apply transitivity with substitution

Tags: relation, coq, transitivity

I want to proof this lemma in Coq:

```
a : Type
b : Type
f : a -> b
g : a -> b
h : a -> b
______________________________________(1/1)
(forall x : a, f x = g x) ->
(forall x : a, g x = h x) -> forall x : a, f x = h x
```

I know that `Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions` defines transitivity for relations:

`Definition transitive : Prop := forall x y z:A, R x y -> R y z -> R x z.`

Simply using the proof tactic `apply transitivity` obviously fails. How can I apply the transitivity lemma to the goal above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `transitivity` tactic requires an argument, which is the intermediate term that you want to introduce into the equality. First call `intros` (that's almost always the first thing to do in a proof) to have the hypotheses nicely in the environment. Then you can say `transitivity (g x)` and you're left with two immediate applications of an assumption.

```
intros.
transitivity (g x); auto.
```

You can also make Coq guess which intermediate term to use. This doesn't always work, because sometimes Coq finds a candidate that doesn't work out in the end, but this case is simple enough and works immediately. The lemma that `transitivity` applies is `eq_trans`; use `eapply eq_trans` to leave a subterm open (`?`). The first `eauto` chooses a subterm that works for the first branch of the proof, and here it also works in the second branch of the proof.

```
intros.
eapply eq_trans.
eauto.
eauto.
```

This can be abbreviated as `intros; eapply eq_trans; eauto`. It can even be abbreviated further to

```
eauto using eq_trans.
```

`eq_trans` isn't in the default hint database because it often leads down an unsuccessful branch.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was on the wrong track. Here is the proof of the lemma:

```
Lemma fun_trans : forall (a b:Type) (f g h:a->b),
  (forall (x:a), f x = g x) ->
  (forall (x:a), g x = h x) ->
  (forall (x:a), f x = h x).
Proof.
    intros a b f g h f_g g_h x.
    rewrite f_g.
    rewrite g_h.
    trivial.
Qed.
```